# Potential Cycle - Lint check

Tags: android, lint

Why does **Lint** throwing the error "**Cycle in resource definitions**"?

My Resources are as follow in themes.xml:
`<style name="Theme.AppName.Holo.Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">`

This themes parent is the **@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog**!

Another Theme is:
`<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="@style/Theme.AppName.Holo.Dark">`

This themes parent is the above **Theme.AppName.Holo.Dark**!

So why should this be a cycle?
A cycle would be if the first themes parent is "Theme.AppName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the naming.
Because of Theme.AppName.Holo.Dark is the first one.

If I change it to:
`<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">`

And the second one to:
`<style name="Theme.AppName.Holo.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.AppName">`

The error is gone away.

Comment: Why would such an error occur between two layout files where one uses an include tag to include the other?